# Mac Outlook showing all links in smart quotes?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I was given the task of fixing my friend's email today and really don't know what the problem is. When an email is sent from his laptop (Mac) from Outlook the email address link in the signature shows exactly like this:

```
email@gmail.com<mailto:email@gmail.com>.
```

Additionally the website link displays like this:

```
www.website.com<http://www.website.com>.
```

And lastly, the image comes through as cid:randomstringofnumbers. When I sent him an email and he sent one back it converted my signature to same weird formatting. Plus, even in the header where it shows our emails, they are displaying the same way:

```
email@gmail.com<mailto:email@gmail.com>.
```

And the weirdest thing is that this problem seems to be "compounding". So when I scroll down to the last, most recent email in the thread I see this

```
www.website.com<http://www.website.com>
```

next email shows this:

```
www.website.com<http://www.website.com><http://www.website.com>
```

and the next this:

```
www.website.com<http://www.website.com><http://www.website.com><http://www.website.com>
```

This is happening to the emails too, everywhere. I'm thinking this might be something to do with smart quotes and the auto formatting but I'm not sure. Could this be the problem? And if so how do I fix it?

Comment: Found out how to fix it for pc but no luck for mac. It's File-> Options-> section: Mail-> button: Editor Options…-> section: Advanced-> option group: Display e-mail content-> uncheck the option: Show field codes instead of their values. If anyone can help me fix this for a mac I'd appreciate it!!